# @Resource not injected sometimes in Spring

Tags: spring, struts2

I have a Spring/Struts2 problem and I have asked in Spring forum but no response
[@Resource no injected sometimes](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?135570-Resource-not-injected-sometimes)

for the ease of reading I will repeat the question here. hopefully its not considered spamming

I have a very strange issue when I use @Resource to inject beans. 
I am using Struts2 2.2.3.1 with provided Spring plugin with Spring 3.0.0. (I am not able to upgrade to the newest version of Spring without knowing the proper cause because all programs are in production)

The issue or observed problem is when an Struts2 Action is created, the fields annotated with @Resource are supposed to have resources injected by Spring. However, some times and only sometimes one of the annotated resources is not inject or the value is simply null and therefore causes NullPointerException. The point where problem occurs is undetermined which mean the same set of programs running in different environment will result in different behaviors. Also the resource that is not injected is not always the same.
For example, if there are actions A, B, C, and environment E1 and E2, in E1 the A action might have this problem sometimes and in E2 it might be action B that's having the problem. One thing that's certain is that if in E2 B is having problem it will happen from time to time and A and C wont have problem or at least the problem just not observed on A and C. Moreover, if A has 5 @Resource fields, when the problem occurs the NPE may be thrown when accessing the first resource however the next time may be the second resource.

Here is what I mean by the problem only happens "sometimes". Suppose A is having this kind of problem, and I start web server (tomcat or WAS) and I go access A for the first time if the problem occurs it will occur throughout the time of this server start-up. If the problem doesn't occur the first time I access A then throughout the time of this server start-up the problem wont occur. Also if this time it's the first resource not injected then it will be the same for this start-up.

Here is a bit of my application setup:
I use XML inter-mixed with annotation scanning. Basically all Action, Service, Dao classes are defined in XML however all property definitions are left out for Spring to scan the actual class.

Sample definition:

Code:

```
<!-- have this in all XML files -->
<context:annotation-config/>

<!-- an action definition, all actions are scoped prototype. It will use adm.common.admBranchesManager in the action with field annotated with @Resource -->
<bean id="adm.common.chooseBranchAction" class="com.bi.wms.adm.common.web.ChooseBranchAction" scope="prototype"></bean>

<!-- all service and dao are singleton and do not have any problem, all service/Manager are annotated with @Transactional. In Action we only code against interface and not actual concrete class -->
<bean id="adm.common.admBranchesManager" class="com.bi.wms.adm.common.service.impl.AdmBranchesManagerImpl"/>


<bean id="adm.common.admBranchesDao" class="com.bi.wms.adm.common.dao.jdbc.AdmBranchesDaoImpl"/>
```

Also for all actions they all extends an abstract action that has a resource field that's session-scoped.

Code:

```
<bean id="base.wms.login" class="com.bi.wms.common.model.WmsLogin" destroy-method="logout" scope="session">
     <aop:scoped-proxy />
     <property name="admUserSessionsManager" ref="adm.operation.admUserSessionsManager"/>
  </bean>
```

Here is a part of a sample action:
Code:

```
//this class is just a sample not the actually one thats having the problem, AbstractWmsAction is the class that have a session-scoped bean
public class AdmWmsControlAction extends AbstractWmsAction
{
    @Resource(name = "adm.operation.admWmsBatchGroupsManager")
    private AdmWmsBatchGroupsManager admWmsBatchGroupsManager;
    @Resource(name = "adm.operation.admWmsControlManager")
    private AdmWmsControlManager admWmsControlManager;

//sometimes we use setters for injecting but that doesnt stop the problem from happening
//....omit
}
```

Don't know if anyone had this kind of issue.
If additional information is needed, I will do my best to provide.

Thanks

Comment: How do you find the annotations in the code?

Comment: sorry i am not sure what you mean by "find the annotations", do you mean how Spring finds my annotation? i supposed that when i define the bean in Spring xml, spring will scan the class automatically and it seems to be the case

Comment: Why not you let it do. Also why do you think you should use Spring to inject the references of the other beans?

Comment: i am letting spring find my annotations for me. I use Spring simply for a choice, I dont think I "should" or not. I am just using it.

Comment: Why are you using `@Resource` for it make the bean as `@Repository` and let the Spring to autowire dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar issues before with Spring using annotations.  Which is why I prefer to use @Transactional in limited situations.  Which classes are annotated with @Transactional? The implementation or the interface?

I've only looked at this quickly through the debugger, but I think you may be ending up with multiple beans, one Spring proxy created with the @Transactional -- ly annotated class, and the other defined in your application context.  I would suggest that if you are defining the service in the Spring configuration file, you also define the transactional proxy there as well, and inject the proxy by name with your @Resource annotation, OR remove the configuration in xml, and inject by type in your annotation.  This way, you'll be notified by Spring if you have duplicate matches by type that cannot be resolved.

Comment: I have all my @ Transactional in my implementation class of Service level and all my Actions code against interface only. Sorry I may not understand Spring that well. I dont get how can Spring proxy create @ Transactional annotated class as well as defined in my application context since I only use context:annotation-config and dont use context:component-scan. I did specify <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="base.transactionManager" />, does that matter?

Comment: no not yet. I have setup log for Spring but since I have setup the log this problem has not occurred yet.
I am trying to get log monitoring in to projects on other sites and see.
do you have any thought on my previous comment?

Comment: Spring always creates a proxy when you use any of the aspect based features (JDBC Template, Transactions etc).  What I've seen in the past is - Not coding/injecting to interfaces and/or having transactional public methods on the implementation that don't match what's on the Service class.  This can cause spring to create a proxy that doesn't match your interface and so not wrapping the class appropriately in the transaction. Like I said, my preference is to make the interface transactional, then I can be sure that the interface being injected is the interface I've defined instead of a proxy.

Comment: I am sure we only inject interfaces, however I will check if anything is marked transactional thats not on the interface.
But what you mean is you add the Transactional annotation on interface instead of the concrete class? But I thought Spring suggested that we put the Transactional annotation on concrete class.

Answer (score 0):

to make a note here
after these time I have not found the real cause and solution.

However, time has proven that upgrading to Spring 2.3.3 or later solves the problem or at least the problem has not appeared yet

Comment: just out of curiosity, did you have context:component-scan element to scan the packages containing spring annotated classes?

Comment: @Atul we do not use annotation to define beans, we only use annotation to define dependencies, so all the beans are defined in xml and we have <context:annotation-config/>.